# iOS Swift Declare Events in code

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I am new to Xcode but have been developing for a 15 years. I am trying to understand how event declaration works in Xcode. Could it possibly be that you can only declare when you Ctr drag it to the code? And then only view it via the dialog box in the Connection Viewer? That would be terribly annoying. What am I missing? Surely the event should appear in the code somewhere.

Here is a sample function that is supposedly declaring a "Did End on Exit" code.

```
@IBAction func helloAction(sender: UITextField) {
   nameLabel.text = "Hi \(sender.text)"
}
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The helloAction method is not declaring a "Did End on Exit" code, unless I'm misunderstanding what you mean by declaring. helloAction is a target that's called when the control it's bound to in Interface Builder receives a Did End on Exit event.

This uses a mechanism known as the Target-Action pattern in Cocoa. A control receives an event, and then calls any methods that have registered to be notified when the control receives that event.

This relationship can be created programmatically as well. Consider the following.

```
let button = UIButton()
button.addTarget(self, action: "tapButton:", forControlEvents:UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
```

When the button is tapped and released with the touch still inside the buttons bounds, `self`'s `tapButton:` method is called.

If you want to learn more about Target-Action in Cocoa, check out a [high level overview](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/Devpedia-CocoaApp/TargetAction.html) or the [definitive discussion](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/Target-Action/Target-Action.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010810-CH12), both from Apple.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Is there a way to not use the IDE to declare the event? @IBAction func actionFunction(event: TouchUpInside)  ?

Comment: Yes, just drop `@IBAction` from the declaration and you won't be able to connect it via Interface Builder. You're then forced to connect it programmatically. So in your original case, the method signature for the code that gets called when the textfield receives the event would be `func helloAction(sender: UITextField)`, and you'd connect it with `myTextField.addTarget(self, action: "helloAction:", forControlEvents:UIControlEvents.EditingDidEndOnExit)`

Comment: You also don't _have_ to drop `@IBAction`. You can programmatically connect the two with it there. `@IBAction` is only an indicator for Interface Builder that the method should be exposed in the IDE UI. AFAIK it doesn't actually change the compiled code.